# How to swap two widgets' x position in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I need to create a function that takes as a parameter two widgets and the frame they are placed.
I want to swap their X position, but I can't figure out the correct way of doing it. This is what I tried:

```
def swap(w1, w2, frame):
    x1 = w1.winfo_x()
    x2 = w2.winfo_x()
    w1.place(x=x2)
    w2.place(x=x1)
    frame.update()
```

What's the right way of doing this? Is this the right approach?

Comment: You code works fine if the two widgets are using `place()` in the first place.

Comment: I use place() in the first place, but with this code the elements both disappear from the window

Comment: Try to print out `x1` and `x2` to see whether they are what you want.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  The code you posted works fine when we make reasonable guesses about the missing code. It would help greatly if you could provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the computed `x1` and `x2` are what you expect they are?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the position using `place_configure`.

Here is an example to swap two labels:

```
from tkinter import *

def swap():
    root.update()
    x1 = label.winfo_x()
    x2 = label2.winfo_x()

    label.place_configure(x=x2)
    label2.place_configure(x=x1)
    
root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text='Hello')
label.place(x=100, y=100)

label2 = Label(root, text='Hello2')
label2.place(x=150, y=100)

btn = Button(root, text='Swap', command=swap)
btn.place(x=125, y=150)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried this out, but unfortunately this still gives me issues: the first element gets correctly placed in the place of the second one, but the second element just disappear for some reason. Is this because I am passing those values as a parameter instead of using global variables?

Comment: @Daniel Can you show your code for me to check? It might be also due to the fact that the second element's width might be too large that the first element gets covered by the second element on swapping.

Comment: The width of the elements are all the same. Here's the code:
```def swap(w1, w2, frame):
    frame.update()
    x1 = w1.winfo_x()
    x2 = w2.winfo_x()

    w1.place_configure(x=x2)
    w2.place_configure(x=x1)```

Comment: This swap function gets called by another function:
```def quick_sort_algorithm(frame):

    widgets = frame.winfo_children()

    swap(widgets[0], widgets[-1], frame)
```

Comment: @Daniel I need to know what is w1 and w2, also why are you passing them as parameters?

Comment: @Daniel can I know where w1 and w2 are placed initially? It's most likely that your second widget is covering the first when you swap.

Comment: The positions initially are 0 and 882. 
w1 and w2 are the parameters of this function, I need them as parameters because I have about 50 widgets in the frame, each representing a number. I want to implement a visualization of the quick sort algorithm

Comment: Note that `place_configure()` is just an alias of `place()`.  So your solution is more or less the same as OP code with the only difference is that your code calls `root.update()` before swapping, whereas OP calls `frame.update()` after swapping.